# merge json under another json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

there is a json like that :

```
json1 = `
{
  "webAPIModification": "`+ new Date() + `",
  "AppSetting": {
    "setting-toastSound": true,
    "setting-animMode": true,
    "setting-landscape": "NAN"
  },
  "UserInfo": {
    "OS": "NAN"
  }
}`;
```

now i have another json like this:

```
json2 = `
{
  "ver": 1,
  "send": true,
  "status": "NAN"
}`;
```

how can add json2 into the json1 (under UserInfo) ?

```
json1 = `
{
  "webAPIModification": "`+ new Date() + `",
  "AppSetting": {
    "setting-toastSound": true,
    "setting-animMode": true,
    "setting-landscape": "NAN"
  },
  "UserInfo": {
    "OS": "NAN",

    "ver": 1, <--> what i need
    "send": true, <--> what i need
    "status": "NAN" <--> what i need

  }
}`;
```

how i can do that in jquery or javascript way???

Comment: Parse it. Manipulate as required then stringify it back to json. You can't do it in jquery because jquery is a javscript library the may have json functions but they'd be rubbish compared to native JSON methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A low level solution could be: use JSON.parse(jsonstring) in order to have objects and treat them as objects with properties or arrays and then you can set what you want... after that you can get the json string with JSON.stringify(object).

```
let obj = JSON.parse(json1);
let otherUserInfo = JSON.parse(json2);

for (var index in otherUserInfo){
     obj.UserInfo[index] = otherUserInfo[index];
}

json1 = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of spread operator and add contents on json2 into json1.

```
const json3 ={
  ...json1,
  UserInfo:{
    ...json1.UserInfo,
    ...json2
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP posted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it into a standard JS object, combine the UserInfo object and finally stringify it back to JSON:

```
a = JSON.parse(json1);
b = JSON.parse(json2);
Object.assign(a.UserInfo, b);
json1 = JSON.stringify(a)
```

Comment: you saved my day. it works fine. also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72967829/16738558) working fine and i accept her answer because he posted faster. +1

Comment: Upvote anyway cause it's a compact and readable solution.